# SSIS transfer from PostgreSQL (UTF-8) to SQL Server (ANSI)

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, utf-8, ssis

I need to create ETL getting data from PostgreSQL to SQL Server. The data on PostgreSQL are in UTF-8, the SQL Server has ANSI.

So I created very simple ETL showing no error (`picture #1`). I am casting the source varchar data via `Derived Column` as shown on `picture #2`. But once launched, ETL returns an error of `Data Truncation`. I assume this is caused by different coding. The data types (both type and length) are the same on both servers. Any ideas?

**Picture #1** 
[image: picture-1]

**Picture #2**
[image: picture-2]

**Error**

```
[Convert] Error: The "Convert" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Convert.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[C_FirstName]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Data Conversion task from the SSIS Toolbox instead of the Derived Column Transformation